# How do I alphabetically sort pointers to characters char** in C?

Tags: arrays, c, bubble-sort

I am new to C. I made my own sorting to sort a bunch of strings alphabetically and this is what I have, but strcmp does not seem to work? The program just crashes.

```
int main(void) {
   char **a = malloc(sizeof(char*));
   a[0] = "Cam";
   a[1] = "Bam";
   a[3] = "Dam";
   a[4] = "Aam";
   for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      for (int j = i+1; a[j] != '\0'; j++)
         if (strcmp(a[i], a[j]) > 0) {
            char* temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
         }
       printf("%s ", a[i]);
     }
   return 0;
}
// output should be Aam Baam Caam Daam
```

Comment: C has [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) which even if you can't use it serves as an example of how you should organize your code: Make a sorting function, don't just do everything in `main()`.

Comment: You only allocated space for 1 pointer, yet you rely on there being 5 (one of which, `a[2]`, is unused).  So of course it crashes.

Comment: Hint: `a[i]` is a `char*` and is not comparable to a NUL byte.

Comment: Instead of bashing around with `malloc`, why not just `char* a[] = { "X", "Y", ... }`? This is a lot harder to foul up because you won't miss entries, like you did, or allocate the wrong size, which is a common mistake. One common C convention is to declare it like `{ "X", ..., NULL }` so you know when to stop iterating and don't need to compute the size.

Comment: The proper way to avoid walking off the end of an array is to have a `length` or `size` variable, and to test `i < size`.

Comment: Hint: When a program "just crashes" the first thing you should do is drop it into a debugger and step through your code line by line. Pay close attention to the variables you've defined and ensure they're set correctly before proceeding to the next statement.

Comment: Thank you all for your help I figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Three issues:

1. You have only allocated space for an array of length 1, but you used 5 slots. To allocate an array of size 5, use `char **a = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));`
2. You never initialized `a[2]`.
3. `a[i] != '\0'` doesn't make much sense since you're comparing a pointer to a char.

Comment: Actually the code requires an additional `NULL` pointer at the end (once the test is fixed to use `NULL` instead of `'\0'`).  So even with the `malloc` call fixed, it will still walk off the end of the array (unless the test is changed to use the array length).

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of confusion in this code about how C works, and a lot of simple mistakes that are avoided if care is taken to pay extremely close attention to the smallest details. In programming a single character can make a world of difference, a tiny slip can change the behaviour of your code dramatically, from working to broken, or from bug-free to completely trashed.

Here's a more idiomatic C version of your code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  // Create a local variable to represent the strings to be sorted
  char *a[] = {
    "E",
    "B",
    "C",
    "A",
    "D",
    NULL // Use NULL as a terminator
  };

  // Iterate over each entry and stop at the NULL terminator...
  for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; a[j]; j++) {
      if (strcmp(a[i], a[j]) > 0) {
        char* temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  // Once the sort has wrapped, print the sorted array
  for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
    // This was erroneously inside the sorting routine before
    printf("%s ", a[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Note, many simple mistakes can be caught using `-Wall` when compiling, or equivalent, where the compiler warns (`-W`) about *everything* (`all`) that it thinks is incorrect.

In `clang` you'd get warnings like:

> sort.c:10:28: warning: comparing a pointer to a null character constant; did you mean to compare to NULL? [-Wpointer-compare]

This helps identify bugs early. Remember in C that "compiles" and "correct" are often worlds apart. A compiler doesn't check much in C other than syntax. The rest is on you, and as a C programmer you have a *lot* of responsibility.

Off-by-one errors, walking off the end of an array, and failing to allocate or free memory are just a few of the many things you need to keep in mind when writing C. This is a language designed to be fast, *not safe*. It's like a race car in that if you don't know how to drive it, you will spin out and go into a wall right away.

Take your time, get some good references, and learn from good examples. You can get the hang of C pretty quickly once you understand what it will and absolutely will not do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've only allocated enough size for a single pointer and yet you're assigning five pointers worth of space.

Try this:

```
char **a = malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);
```